# Package requirements (x11) were not met (set the environment variables)

Tags: package-management, mesa

So today I went to install `Mesa - 9.0.1` from 01.org but wasn't sure how to compile it so I found a site that said you could convert the contents of `.tar.gz` files into .debs by using alien. So I converted it and went to install it. It appeared to install fine but it wasn't installed and when I later went to the package manager it says the package catalogue is broken and needs to be repaired. But it won't repair.

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libglapi-mesa_9.0.1-0ubuntu1~precise7.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):  './usr/share/doc/libglapi-mesa/changelog.Debian.gz' is different from the same file on the system dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2 Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx (from .../libgl1-mesa-glx_9.0.1-0ubuntu1~precise7.3_amd64.deb) ... 
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-glx_9.0.1-0ubuntu1~precise7.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):  './usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-glx/changelog.Debian.gz' is different from the same file on the system dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing:  /var/cache/apt/archives/libglapi-mesa_9.0.1-0ubuntu1~precise7.3_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-glx_9.0.1-0ubuntu1~precise7.3_amd64.deb Error in function:
```

So I go in the synaptic package manager where it tells me I have 22 packages broken on my system. They're all dependant of `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `libglapi-mesa`. So I go to reinstall it/them repair it/ whatever but it doesn't work 'cause the package manager won't let me install anything 'cause these two files are dependant on the others as well.

tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa

sudo apt-get -f autoremove

sudo apt-get remove libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa

sudo apt-get clean
```

etc. following advice from other sites with no luck.

So I go to compile the original `Mesa - 9.0.1` folder and run `./configure`, what I should have done in the first place, and it tells me of other dependencies which I install but now it tells me I don't have x11 but I'm pretty sure I must do:

```
checking for X11... no configure: error: Package requirements (x11) were not met:

No package 'x11' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables X11_CFLAGS and X11_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

Please could you tell me how "set the environment variables X11_CFLAGS and
X11_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config." ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't have the xorg development libraries, a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

should fix that error message. I would recommend to use:

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep mesa
```

instead, to assure that all dependencies are installed.